# Click listener crashes device

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, clicklistener

Can you tell me why this click listener crashes the Android device when the user enters the settings screen?

```
    /*
     * Create the preference from the xml file. This will be used in a click
     * listener.
     */
    Preference settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated = (Preference)  findPreference("checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated");

    settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference  preference) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Here is the settings.xml file related to this click listener.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/category_title_wallpaper">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated"
        android:title="@string/item_title_change_wallpaper"   android:summary="@string/item_summary_change_wallpaper"
        android:defaultValue="false" />

    <ListPreference android:title="@string/list_title_time_before_changing_wallpaper"
        android:key="list_time_before_changing_wallpaper" android:summary="@string/list_summary_time_before_changing_wallpaper"
        android:entries="@array/label_time_before_changing_wallpaper"
        android:entryValues="@array/value_time_before_changing_wallpaper"
        android:defaultValue="Default" />

    <!-- -->
</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

If the click listener is commented out than the settings screen can be displayed so it looks like there's something wrong with the xml file or the click listener.

If I can get it to work, then I will put the additional coding before the return statement.

Thanks.

Truly,
Emad

Update:

This is the entire class that is now working thanks for everyone's help:

```
import hajj.auto.wallpaper.R;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

SharedPreferences pref;

/*
 * This is called when the class is created. It displays a Settings screen
 * from the settings.xml file.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*
     * Read the settings definition from XML and show them in the current
     * activity (screen).
     */
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    /*
     * This Preference Manager is required for the change listener to work.
     */
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    /*
     * This will allow changes in lists to be trapped.
     */
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    /*
     * Create the preference from the xml file. This will be used in a click
     * listener.
     */

    CheckBoxPreference settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_changing_is_activated");

    //Preference settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated");

    settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new CheckBoxPreference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            boolean activated = (Boolean) newValue;
           // updateStuff(activated);
            return true;


        }
    });


} // End method onCreate.

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

} // End method onSharedPreferenceChanged.

private void finishThisActivity() {
    this.finish();
} // End method finishThisActivity.
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace that gets produced when the application crashes?

Comment: Hi slayton, I added the LogCat if that is what you mean by stracktrace. Thanks.

Comment: CheckBoxPreference settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated"); try this.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I got it to work with both of your help. I first tried the code in the above comment but it still crashed. Next I tried to shorten the preference name from "checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated" to "checkbox_changing_is_activated" and it did not crash. Looks like at least on my computer there is some sort of limitation on how long these names can be. Again, thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code, you're using a `Preference` object, when in the XML you have a `CheckBoxPreference`. Those are two different things, and you can't cast one to the other, if I recall correctly.

Also, the appropriate listener that I think you are wanting is

```
CheckBoxPreference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {
            // Your code here. Make good use of preference and newValue.
            // You can cast newValue to boolean, for example.
        }
}
```

Full working sample:

```
Preference settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated");

settingWallpaperChangingIsActivated.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new CheckBoxPreference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {


        boolean activated = (Boolean) newValue;
        updateStuff(activated);
        return true;


    }
});
```

Comment: Oops, my answer has a small problem. Use CheckBoxPreference on both sides when initalizing. I copied-pasted your sample and forgot to change that.

Comment: Hi David, I get an error that says "CheckBoxPreference cannot be resolved to a type". Did I miss something?

Comment: You need to import it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html If you're using Eclipse to develop, there should be a hint to use it. otherwise, place (no quotes) in your import list: "import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;"

Comment: Hi David, Yes I'm using Eclipse. The import is also there when it crashed.

Comment: Hi David, Do you think my preference name "checkbox_change_wallpaper_is_activated" is too long? Maybe there is some restriction on how long it can be.

Comment: I doubt it. I don't know what is the limit, but it's probably huge. I also use huge identifiers, never had a problem. I'm stunned because you're saying that the import is there, but at the same time it can't be resolved to a type. I don't know why, considering you verified your imports list.

Comment: Hi David, I'm including the complete class so maybe you can see what I did wrong with it.

Comment: Hi David, I tried to save the code but I did not know the save failed so here it is in the update sections of this post. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you and you're welcome. Thanks for letting us know that the length may be a problem. And you're welcome, I'm glad this quick answer helped you detect the CheckBoxPreference issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error is on line 51 of `hajj.auto.wallpaper.free.SettingsActivity` in the `onCreate()` method.  I can't tell you anymore than that without seeing that code.  Although I guess it is probably because you try to add a listener to an object that hasn't been initialized yet (is probably still `null`).

Comment: Hi David, I erased the wording and let the intellisense fill it in and it compiled ok but still crashes.

Comment: Hi Slayton, Should I use a pref editor and set it to false before calling the settings screen because I was hoping the default value statement in the xml file would have given it a value? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Slayton, Line 51 of the onCreate() method is the click listener coding.

Comment: Opps, I meant change listener.

Comment: You don't need to use text editors, you don't even need to put the "android:defaultValue" in the preferences XML file. For each preference, Android provides defaults automatically (for checkbox, I believe it's false, but don't remember right now). Of course, the internal preferences file won't be changed until the user actually interact with the widget. Also, because you don't need to doesn't mean you shouldn't. Generally, people create a defaults generator and check for it when the user first run the app. It's a common pattern.

Comment: About your other comment, I believe the compiler is trying to tell you that there is no Preference with that name on the preferences XML file (there is a CheckBoxPreference). Since it can't find it, the object is null. And when you try to set the listener to a null object, you get a null exception. That's my guess.